# warning: managed-keys-zone/admins: No DNSKEY RRSIGs found for '.': success

Tags: domain-name-system, centos7, bind

I just finished to install my master nameserver (ns1), but still have a warning...

```
warning: managed-keys-zone/admins: No DNSKEY RRSIGs found for '.': success 
warning: managed-keys-zone/others: No DNSKEY RRSIGs found for '.': success
```

My config :

```
//
// named.conf
//
//
// Ansible managed
//
acl "acl-allow-transfer" {
  192.168.2.100;
};
acl "acl-all-admins" {
  192.168.10.0/24;
};
acl "acl-no-admin" {
  localhost;
  192.168.1.0/24;
};
acl "acl-allow-recursion" {
  localhost;
  192.168.10.0/24;
};
acl "acl-allow-query" {
  localhost;
  192.168.10.0/24;
  192.168.1.0/24;
};

options {
  listen-on port 53 { any; };
  listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
  directory   "/var/named";
  dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
  statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
  memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
  allow-query     { acl-allow-query; };
  allow-transfer { acl-allow-transfer; };

  empty-zones-enable no;

  recursion yes;
  allow-recursion { acl-allow-recursion; };
  # Forwarders are openDNS servers
  forwarders { 8.8.8.8; };

  dnssec-enable no;
  dnssec-validation no;
  dnssec-lookaside no;  

  allow-update { none; };

  allow-update-forwarding { none; };

  allow-notify { none; };

  rrset-order { order random; };

  /* Path to ISC DLV key */
  bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

  managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

  pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
  session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
  channel default_debug {
    file "/var/log/named.log" versions 30 size 2m;
    severity info;
    print-severity yes;
    print-time yes;
  };
};


view admins {

  match-clients { acl-all-admins; };

  zone "intra.mycomp.fr" IN {
    type master;
    file "masters/admins.intra.mycomp.fr";
  };
  zone "fixe.mycomp.fr" IN {
    type master;
    file "masters/fixe.mycomp.fr";
  };
  zone "mobile.mycomp.fr" IN {
    type master;
    file "masters/mobile.mycomp.fr";
  };

  zone « 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "masters/1.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
  };
  zone "10.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "masters/10.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
  };

  include "/etc/named.root.key";
  include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";

};
view others {

  match-clients { acl-no-admin; };

  zone "intra.mycomp.fr" IN {
    type master;
    file "masters/others.intra.mycomp.fr";
  };
  zone "fixe.mycomp.fr" IN {
    type master;
    file "masters/fixe.mycomp.fr";
  };
  zone "mobile.mycomp.fr" IN {
    type master;
    file "masters/mobile.mycomp.fr";
  };

  zone « 1.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
    type master;
    file "masters/1.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
  };

  include "/etc/named.root.key";
  include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";

};
```

Have an idea ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Pierre

Comment: Start by separating the recursive and authoritative roles into 2 separate servers. Having them both in the same one will only lead to problems. Also remove everything related to DLV, this is now defunct. Does your server have access to the root zone by DNS queries?

Comment: Ah yes I know about separating roles, but my nameservers are only visible by local networks... And I'm a bit limitated by ressources (cpu / ram) to create more virtual machines...
Ok concerning DLV, but sorry I don't understand the question about root zone ?
(And about my warnings it disapeared once I changed the forwarders (OpenDNS servers to google nameservers).

Answer (score 0):

You can remove following line in /etc/named.conf file

include "/etc/named.root.key";

After the modification, make sure to restart named.service:

#systemctl restart named